# Merging multiple List of Entities into One List in Java

Tags: java, spring

Is there any possibility to merge Multiple List of Entities into One. Below is the Code :

```
public List getList() {
List<MyClass1> list1 = someService.getList1();
List<MyClass2> list2 = someService.getList2();
List<MyClass1> list3 = someService.getList3();
List<MyClass1> list4 = someService.getList4();
//Some merging operation
return ..... }
```

Please note that MyClass1, MyClass2 .... are all entities which contains different attributes.

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: It's possible, but it's not a good idea to mix types in a list.  How are you going to know what the type is when you pull it back out of the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use object

```
List<Object> newlist = new ArrayList<>();
newlist.add(list1);
```